# Why positive response is always plus 40 and negative response is 7F in UDS,KWP diagnostic protocol in automotive?

Tags: diagnostics

i want logical reason why positive response is +40 and negative response is 7F in UDS i tried some diagnostic services but getting always +40 and 7F but not getting why always it is increment by +40

Comment: yes where i will get details about this?

Answer (score 2):

In UDS the first byte of a positive response is always `SID + 40 hex` (SID = Service Identifier, the first byte of the request) and the first byte of a negative response is always `7F hex`: simply because it is defined like this in the international standards **ISO14229-1** (former ISO 15765-3). There is no further logical reason - theoretically other proprietary diagnostic protocols could use different offset values to indicate positive/negative responses: It's an arbitrary choice when designing a diagnostic protocol.

But historically using `40 hex` as offset for positive responses has a long tradition in diagnostics; used i.e. in **KWP2000 (ISO 14230)** and **OBD (SAE J1979 / ISO 15031)** protocols respectively.

Using a single bit (`Bit 6`) to differentiate between requests and responses has certain advantages; it is trivial to distinguish between them for any application which needs to interpret the data; If `Bit 6` is set the byte needs to be checked only against the constant value `7F hex` to know if the response is positive or negative.

Comment: UDS definitions are mentioned in ISO14229-1 Road vehicles - Unified Diagnostic Services. ISO 15765 is CAN transport layer protocol, UDS is independent of transport layer and below in the OSI model.

Comment: @Kumar Only ISO 15765-2 is about the transport layer, ISO 15765-3 is "Implementation of unified diagnostic services (UDS on CAN)".

Comment: Yes, the +40h rule should be designed by someone a longtime ago , probably someone in bosch

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the bytes allocation for Postive and Negative Responses. If so the ODX embedding each function/device have been predefined to respond with those NRC's and PRC's. Hope this gives or explains your question

Comment: As per Standard diagnostic iso-15765-2
=============================================================
**0x01-0x3E,0x80-0xBE**-Service request
0x3F- Reserved
0x7F is for negative responses
0x40-0x7E,0xC0-0xFE- Positive response 


To get positive response always in range of  
0x40-0x7E,0xC0-0xFE we have to add +40 to service request ID

Answer (score 0):

There is one Dedicated bit to differentiates the positive and negative response for every positive response the 6 bit in the particular Service id bit will be changed to 1.

for example you need the service of 10 then
      XX 10 02 XX XX XX XX XX  - 0001 0000  - 10    (UDS service) 
      XX 50 02 XX XX XX XX XX  - 0101 0000  - 50    (for positive response)
  for 2E service
      XX 2E XX XX XX XX XX XX  - 0010 1110   - 2E    (UDS service ID)
      XX 6E XX XX XX XX XX XX  - 0110 1110   - 6E    (Positive Response)

from the above you can observe only 6th bit is going to change for every positive response.

Please find this link for exact answer

https://youtu.be/bh1xvtVinXE

Comment: This answer is wrong; Bit 6 is not dedicated to differentiate between **positive** and **negative** response, but to differentiate between **request** and **response**. 7F hex has Bit 6 set too!

Comment: because of that bit 6 only we are going to know the response for the particular request is correct or not.so,the bit 6 is used for indication for response is correct or not.